# How to decrease my repeated code

Tags: java, android

Hi How I write these several code in only one line

```
            if (stimee.getText().toString().equals("0")) {stimevar="00"; } 
            if (stimee.getText().toString().equals("1")) {stimevar="01"; } 
            if (stimee.getText().toString().equals("2")) {stimevar="02"; } 
            if (stimee.getText().toString().equals("3")) {stimevar="03"; } 
            if (stimee.getText().toString().equals("4")) {stimevar="04"; } 
            if (stimee.getText().toString().equals("5")) {stimevar="05"; } 
            if (stimee.getText().toString().equals("6")) {stimevar="06"; } 
            if (stimee.getText().toString().equals("7")) {stimevar="07"; } 
            if (stimee.getText().toString().equals("8")) {stimevar="08"; } 
            if (stimee.getText().toString().equals("9")) {stimevar="09"; }
```

Comment: Something like `stimevar = "0" + stimee.getText().toString();` You will need some prevalidation before that.

Comment: Use some kind of Map

Answer (score 2):

all you really need is:

```
stimevar="0"+stimee.getText().toString();
```

since i dont see an else clause in your question, this must solve your problem.

Comment: Isn't it just my comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Map` to store the values and then set the variable.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("0", "00");
map.put("0", "01");
...
map.put("9", "09");

stimevar = map.get(stimee.getText().toString());
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is, that `stimevar` can become `null`. This might need to be avoided.

Comment: @Tom That's true, but what I don't like about other approaches is that they rely on the format of `getText()` which is later parsed to integer. The dual question would be, what would happen if `getText()` is not a valid string?

Comment: When will that happen? `stimee` seems to be a [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)(according to the `android` tag) and `getText()` returns its content. It should always be a String.

Comment: The solutions that concatenate the string are fine, but the ones that use `parseInt(stimee.getText().toString())`. I mean if it is "xyz".

Answer (score 0):

```
// parse input value as integer
int value = Integer.parseInt(stimee.getText().toString());
// check input for values from 0 to 9
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
  // if found a match
  if (value == i) {
    // set variable
    stimevar = String.format("%02d", i);
    // and stop checking
    break;
  } 
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to @Tom for pointing out parsing the String only once beforehand would be more effective.

Comment: This is a very strange approach. Wouldn't it make much more sense to parse that String *once* and then check its value?

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = stimee.getText().toString();
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    if (("" + i).equals(str))
         stimevar = "0" + i;
```